# Getting the points at which the tangent plane is horizontal?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the equation: 
$$
z = xy(3-x-y).
$$
Find all the points where the tangent plane is horizontal. I found $Fx = Fy = 0$ and got to the following system: 
$$
\begin{cases}
3x - x^2 - xy = 0\\
3y-2xy-y^2 = 0
\end{cases}
$$
I tried solving it and got two points- $(0,0)$ and $(0,3)$, however the solution to this problem says there are two extra solutions: $(3,0)$ and $(1,1)$. A bit confused as to how to get this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.StockExchange. This is a good question, but your post can be improved by editing your formulas. Try wrapping your equations with dollar signs, so the website automatically formats them accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you have a miscalculation in your first equation (the $-xy$ term should be $-2xy$) and that each of your two equations factor:

$$\begin{cases} x(3 - x - 2y) = 0 \\ y(3 - 2x - y) = 0 \end{cases}.$$

Thus you have to consider four possibilities:

(1) $ x = y = 0$

(2) $ x = 3 - 2x - y = 0$

(3) $ 3 - x - 2y = y = 0$

(4) $ 3 - x - 2y = 3 - 2x - y = 0$

This will produce the four total solutions you are seeking.